# Pass array of objects as param to SOAP function and php-wsdl

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapui

i'm trying to setup a SOAP server with a function that reads an array of objects as parameter. I'm generating WSDL with php-wsdl. Here's my approach:

```
/**
 * TStanMag
 * 
 *
 * @pw_set nillable=false The next element can't be NULL
 * @pw_element string $kodTowaru Kod towaru
 * @pw_set nillable=false The next element can't be NULL
 * @pw_element float $ilosc Dostępna ilość
 * @pw_complex TStanMag Pozycja stanu magazynowego
 */
class TStanMag {
    public $kodTowaru;
    public $ilosc;
};
```

...

```
/**
 * Aktualizacja stanów magazynowych
 * 
 * @param string $key1 Klucz 1
 * @param string $key2 Klucz 2
 * @param TStanMag[] $stany Tabela stanów magazynowych
 * @param int $store_id
 * @return TResult[] Response
 */
public function AktualizujStanyMagazynowe($key1, $key2, $stany, $store_id = 0) {
...
}
```

but in WSDL i see this type instead of array of types:

```
<wsdl:part name="stany" type="tns:TStanMag[]">
<s:documentation>Tabela stanów magazynowych</s:documentation>
</wsdl:part>
```

also getting warning in SoapUI

```
Thu Mar 19 21:04:38 CET 2015:WARN:Failed to find type [{http://localhost/symsync/}TStanMag[]]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you share the whole `wsdl`? is `TStanMag` type defined inside schema defined with `http://localhost/symsync/` namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I solved this. Working code below.

```
/**
 * TStanMag
 * 
 *
 * @pw_set nillable=false The next element can't be NULL
 * @pw_element string $kodTowaru Kod towaru
 * @pw_set nillable=false The next element can't be NULL
 * @pw_element float $ilosc Dostępna ilość
 * @pw_complex TStanMag Pozycja stanu magazynowego
 */
class TStanMag {
    public $kodTowaru;
    public $ilosc;
};

/**
 * TStanMagArray
 * 
 *
 * @pw_element TStanMag $TStanMag Kod towaru
 * @pw_complex TStanMagArray Tablica pozycji stanu magazynowego
 */
class TStanMagArray {
    public $TStanMag;
};
```

...

```
/**
     * Aktualizacja stanów magazynowych
     * 
     * @param string $key1 Klucz 1
     * @param string $key2 Klucz 2
     * @param TStanMagArray $stany Tabela stanów magazynowych
     * @param int $store_id
     * @return TResultArray Response
     */
    public function AktualizujStanyMagazynowe($key1, $key2, $stany, $store_id = 0) {
```

Comment: What did you do, please explain. It will other SO users will gain.

Comment: What I needed was creating TStanMagArray class as declared above. Note the ...Array suffix is needed by php-wsdl parser to "recognize" it.